# React: Element type is invalid in one component but not the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to react, but I'm running into a problem that is throwing me for a loop. 
Is there any reason that react would throw a `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` error when instantiating a component, but not when instantiating another component that literally has the exact same code?

Heres what I've got:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Method from "./Method";

class InterfaceContent extends Component {

renderInterface = (interfaceItem, index) => {
    const itemKey = `interface-Item-${index}`;
    const {Name, Interface, Method} = interfaceItem;

    return (
        <div key={itemKey}>
            <p>{Name}</p>
            <div className="interface-item-method">
                {(interfaceItem.Method.length >= 1) ? <Method Method={interfaceItem.Method}/> : null}
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="interfacecontent-component">
            <h3 className="interfaces">Interfaces</h3>
            {this.props.Interfaces.map(this.renderInterface)}
        </div>
    );
 }
}
export default InterfaceContent;
```

Im getting some data back from an API that I'm going through and displaying on the page. A lot of the data has nested arrays, but anything that has Methods is all coming back in the same format.

And I get the error when trying to render out the `<Method />` component, which looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Method extends Component {

renderMethod = (method, index) => {
    const itemKey = `method-item-${index}`;
    const {DeprecatedSince, Description, Example, Name, Since, Argument, Return } = method;

    return(
        <div key={itemKey} className="method">
        <h2>Name: {Name}</h2>
        <h2>Description: {Description}</h2>
        <h2>DeprecatedSince : {DeprecatedSince}</h2>
        <h2>Example : {Example}</h2>
        <h2>Since : {Since}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="method-component">
            {this.props.Method.map(this.renderMethod)}
        </div>
    );
 }
}

export default Method;
```

Whats confusing is the `interfaceItem.Method` data that I'm passing to the `<Method />` component is the exact same structure-wise as I've used before in the app. So, just to test, I made an `<InterfaceMethod />` component that, besides the name, is copy/pasted exact same code from the `<Method />` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class InterfaceMethod extends Component {

renderMethod = (method, index) => {
    const itemKey = `method-item-${index}`;
    const {DeprecatedSince, Description, Example, Name, Since, Argument, Return } = method;

    return(
        <div key={itemKey} className="method">
        <h2>Name: {Name}</h2>
        <h2>Description: {Description}</h2>
        <h2>DeprecatedSince : {DeprecatedSince}</h2>
        <h2>Example : {Example}</h2>
        <h2>Since : {Since}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="method-component">
            {this.props.Method.map(this.renderMethod)}
        </div>
    );
 }
}

export default InterfaceMethod;
```

Which renders just fine without errors. 
Everything Ive googled concerning the `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` error seems to come up with the end being `but got: undefined` and ends up being an error with how something was imported.

That doesnt seem to be the case here. I am using the `<Method/>` component in a few other places throughout the app that I need to render similar content - would there be a reason that would interfere? I'd hate to have two components with the same code inside them floating around if I can avoid it.

Comment: could you try this 

```
    {(interfaceItem.Method.length >= 1) && <Method Method=
    {interfaceItem.Method}/>}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be the error is when you destructure your `interfaceItem` in your `renderInterface` method in `InterfaceContent` component.

```
renderInterface = (interfaceItem, index) => {
    const itemKey = `interface-Item-${index}`;
    const {Name, Interface, Method} = interfaceItem;

    return (
        <div key={itemKey}>
            <p>{Name}</p>
            <div className="interface-item-method">
                {(interfaceItem.Method.length >= 1) ? <Method Method={interfaceItem.Method}/> : null}
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

What happening is when you render your Method component (using `<Method />`), it is not the actual component but the Method array that you destructured from interfaceItem. And that is why you are getting the array, as your are trying to render a object and not a react component.

Comment: Awesome. I took the `Method` out of the destructing in the `renderInterface` method and that seemed to work with the `<Method />` component. I still find it weird that  `<InterfaceMethod />` - which is the exact same code as `<Method />` rendered fine previously. Anyway - Thank you!

Comment: There wasn't any problem with your `Method` component. When you used `<Method />`, the `Method` was not your component but the array that was destructured from the interfaceItem. Your variable Method was holding an array and not the actual Method component.